# Python: Referencing multiple values to a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a complete noob at python so I apologize if I didn't even phrase the title correctly... I have some data that look like this:

```
array([[   5, 9, 4, 11, -22.949, 0   ],
       [   5, 10, 3, 14, -22.454, 0   ],
          ........................
       [   4, 11, 4, 14, -21.952, 0   ]])
```

where the first four columns refer to two pairs of map data.
I also have a map key that I managed to put into a dictionary:

```
{'9': ['5', '9'],
 '10': ['5', '10'],
 ..............
 '64': ['4', '11']}
```

Basically I am looking to create a new text file where the map data is replaced with the dictionary key, so:

```
array([[5, 9, 4, 11, -22.949, 0]]
```

would look like

```
array([[9, 64, -22.949, 0]]
```

I have only used python for plots and some calculations (essentially an automated Excel...) so I would appreciate any help with this problem. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind how `5,9,4,11` turns into `{9: [5,9]}`. Also, where did `64` come frome?

Comment: The coordinates in the original file are (5,9), and (4,11). In the map key ['5', '9'] = 9, and ['4', '11'] = 64. so in my final output  would replace the pairs (5,9) and (4,11) with 9 and 64. The 9 and 64 are just some arbitrary numbers we assigned to each pair of coordinates. Hope that make sense >.<

Comment: Are these arbitrary numbers captured/noted somewhere? If not, it would be impossible to construct a data structure that holds that data

Comment: The map key is stored in a  separate .csv file with 3 columns that looks like (1,5,9)...(64,4,11)

Comment: The array that you mentioned in your question - is it generated from a csv file as well?

Comment: Yes it is. 15char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import operator


coords = operator.itemgetter(0,1,2,3)
with open('path/to/data.csv') as infile, open('path/to/mapkey.csv') as mapfile:
    ids = {}
    for row in csv.reader(mapfile):
        name, x, y = map(int, row)
        ids[(x,y)] = name

    answer = []
    for x,y, a,b in map(coords, csv.reader(infile)):
        answer.append([ids[(x,y)]], ids[(a,b)]])
```

This should give you `answer`, which is a 2d list with two map keys in each sublist